# Download manager in android?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Hi have simple app in which data has been uploaded from the **web server** I am using **.net web services**. I need to replace the document on same location, so that duplicate document not place on same folder.

**I am using:**

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                                  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Downloads",
                                  name );
```

**is it right approach?** can I delete document from physical place and then replace it with new one. if yes How this thing is possible.

this is my download manager and I am trying to delete name document and then trying to replace with new one. Please suggest. thanks

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setTitle(name); 
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();               
    request.setNotificationVisibility(
                     DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
               Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Downloads", name);
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: You have to download file first then remove old one and move new downloaded file to your directory.